# Task Scheduler failed ... Error Value 2147942402

Tags: windows, windows-10, scheduled-task, windows-command-prompt, task-scheduler

I tried to schedule a task by

```
schtasks /create /tn Test /sc minute /mo 1 /tr "del /f \"%UserProfile%\path\file\""
```

...however the Scheduler always ends up with the following type of error:

> Task Scheduler failed to launch action "del" in instance
>   "{a6c5962d-ed1e-4917-9d43-07525dd03218}" of task "\Test". Additional
>   Data: Error Value: 2147942402

The file in the path exists. I can run the same `del` command from console and it deletes the file successfully, but I cannot make it work with scheduled task.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried running it with highest credentials?

Comment: @Davidw - Yes, in the elevated mode as administrator. No difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where del
```

> ```
> INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
> ```

Use

```
/TR "\"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe\" /C del /f \"%UserProfile%\path\file\""
```

Comment: Děkuji Josefe (Thank you, Josef)

Comment: What I am suppose to do to prevent to show a command prompt window when the scheduler runs the task? Currently it shows and immediately closes the command prompt window, which is unwanted and annoying. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: [How to prevent command window from appearing on scheduled tasks on Windows 10](https://pureinfotech.com/prevent-command-window-appearing-scheduled-tasks-windows-10/) works however I don't know how to do that using `schtasks.exe` tool without `/XML xmlfile` where `xmlfile` contains `<LogonType>S4U</LogonType>`.

Comment: I was looking for a direct way using command, not through the user interface.

Comment: Please cf [Prevent Windows PowerShell console from flashing up](https://serverfault.com/q/1003763/257436).